# Linux parse multiple text files into separate files

Tags: regex, linux, bash, parsing, split

I have 100 text files, each file approx 1gb size, all in the same folder
each file contains many info separated by blocks like in dumped sql database files

each block started with string "Create Table `"
each block ending with string "Table structure for table"

As I have note experience in Linux I want to ask you How in linux write script, which loop from all files in folder, for each file split this file by block, and saved this blocks to separate txt files named as each block starting string, and all each file block put in different folder named as filename.

```
For example, logic must be such as

For each file in folder
  Create xFolder Named as file

  For each match by regex((Create Table `).*(Table structure for table))
    Create file in xFolder named as regex((Create Table `).*`) (Extract name between ` `` from this match)
    Put matched text to file
  Next match
Next file
```

So if file  MyFirstFile.txt contains 3 blocks:

```
Create Table `Table1` (
text
text
...
text )
- Table structure for table

Create Table `Table2` (
text
text
...
text )
- Table structure for table

Create Table `Table3` (
text
text
...
text )
- Table structure for table
```

Then must be created folder with name MyFirstFile
In this folder 3 txt files Table1.txt, Table2.txt, Table3.txt

```
Table1.txt must have inside

    Create Table `Table1` (
    text
    text
    ...
    text )
    - Table structure for table

Table2.txt must have inside

    Create Table `Table2` (
    text
    text
    ...
    text )
    - Table structure for table

Table3.txt must have inside

    Create Table `Table3` (
    text
    text
    ...
    text )
    - Table structure for table
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code design and writing service. You need to show some effort into doing the work yourself before you can expect much assistance from us. As it stands your question is likely to be voted down and closed as not showing enough research on your part.

Answer (score 0):

Take one file(file1.txt) as example:

```
for table_name in `grep "Create Table" file1.txt | awk '{print $3}'`
do
   awk '/Create Table '"$table_name"'/{print;while(getline)if($0 !~/Create Table/)print;else exit}` file1.txt > $table_name.txt
done
```

For all files just one more loop. Try it by yourself.

Good Luck!